# How to attach email to another email with end result where top level mail content-type message/rfc822 in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime-types, email-attachments, mime-message

I had looked into email lib of python but did not find any reference where it suggests way to attach mail to mail with content-type message/rfc822.

```
   #Message to be attached to new mail
   parsed_message = email.message_from_string(str(desearilized_message))

   msg = MIMEMultipart() 
   
   msg['From'] = "somesender@send.me" 
  
   msg['To'] = "somereciver@recive.me"

   msg['Subject'] = "Subject of the Mail"
 
   body = "Body_of_the_mail"
  
   msg.attach(parsed_message)
```

This results in parent mail with Content-Type: multipart and not message/rfc822.
Any reference/suggestion of how to achieve it in python3?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
msg = EmailMessage()
  
msg.__setitem__("Content-type","message/rfc822")
```